# Inserting numbers from file deliminted by dash into BST in C++

Tags: c++, integer, binary-search-tree, ifstream

I am attempting to write a program that will read numbers from a file and insert them into a binary search tree.  The files I'm attempting to read are large (over a million numbers) but the first file begins this way:

**298267282091408035-17044748745909945522138999443630343281-7437445665634475999134759620996365304-30967249084947458298112694712508035495502810273077177769044463844948009893353572884251867099313-5749770665631259681-3280801305990840625-9197941794449524441-147424278867187802328369201167366083797795701747773283129-47949538648841990716317462836568229334
-...**

where the numbers are delimited by dashes (and there is no new line character so, theoretically, it could  all go on to one line).

I'm honestly quite confused as to how to go about this.  Here's what I have so far but I know for a fact that it's wrong.  I'm just not sure how to fix it.

```
    cout << "File to be read: " << flush;
    string fileName;
    cin >> fileName;
    fstream in;
    in.open(fileName.c_str());
    assert(in.is_open());
    while(in.good()){
        int num = in.get();
        BST bst;
        while(isalnum(num)){
            try{
                bst.insert(num);
            } catch(Exception& e){
                cerr << "error" << flush;
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm also trying to have a way to indicate if a value is duplicated and handle the exception it causes (because duplicate values can't be inserted into a BST).

I know I'm not providing much help with regard to this question but I'm just not sure how to go about it.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `getline` with `'-'` as delimiter.

like this:

```
string temp;
std::getline(cin, temp, '-');
```

and BTW: look like `int` is not sufficient to the given numbers, some of them are really big. too big even for `long long int` type.

maybe it is better to keep them as strings.